# How to do this programmatically in wpf

Tags: wpf, tooltip

How to do this programmatically in wpf

1. Submit Request
                   Submits the request to the server.

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to do.  Could you add more detail?

Comment: To those who are editing, please don't change the content of the question.  This question is NOT about XAML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 ToolTip toolTip = new ToolTip();
 StackPanel stack = new StackPanel();
 stack.Children.Add(new TextBlock() { Text = "Submit Request", FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold });
 stack.Children.Add(new TextBlock() { Text = "Submits the request to the server." });
 toolTip.Content = stack;
```

Comment: I think the previous edit to the question changed the meaning.  Unfortunately this means this answer doesn't answer the question.